# How to limit access to my graphql endpoint using Cors or any other node module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, graphql

I'm working on a React/NodeJS, I'm using graphql between the front and the backend.

My frontend PWA application has a link similar to : https://app.domain.com.

My backend api has a link similar to : https://api.domain.com.

I want to protect my GraphQL endpoint (https://api.domain.com/graphql) from any request call not coming from my PWA Application (https://app.domain.com).

Is there any good solution to do that ? using CORS or any other library ?

I did try this in my backend, but still not working :

```
app.use(cors({origin:'https://app.domain.com'}));


//My graphql config
app.use("/graphql",
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema: buildSchema(schema),
    rootValue: indexResolver,
    graphiql: true,
    context: { request: req }
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
const allowedOrigins = ['https://app.domain.com'];

app.use(cors({
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
        'allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));
```